# Page like by application

Tags: facebook-like

Is there a possibility to programaticaly like facebook page from facebook application - by add user to /PAGE_ID/likes or something like this?

Comment: user has to like your page,,,,,,,,,,, programmatically you can't make me to like your page,,,,,,,may be you can try some hidden codes behind button can sometimes do!.........

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically "like" a Facebook page within an iOS app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5214138/how-to-programmatically-like-a-facebook-page-within-an-ios-app)

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutly no way.

You can only use the social plugins Facebook provides for liking, but the user has to engage with them (a.k.a. click) himself.